# recibiendo este ID de recurso n.º 12

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

No estoy segura de por qué, pero esto está devolviendo el valor. ESTABA recibiendo este ID de recurso n.º 12, en lugar del valor "VEF o USD" que estoy buscando ..

el código que hice esto fue:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT moneda FROM tarifas";
$resul = mysql_query($sql1,$link);
```

Luego lo cambio a este:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT moneda FROM tarifas";
$resul = mysql_query($sql1,$link);
$mon= mysql_fetch_array($resul);
```

Y aqui me da como resultado "Array"

Comment: el resultado que ves es correcto. Estas recibiendo un array. Ahora tenes que buscar el resultado que vos queres adentro. Pero si al select no le agregas una condicion de filtro va a traer todos los datos de la tabla

Comment: @Andrea Valentina Exactamente como te dice gbianchi si queires solo recibir un resultado te falta agregar un where a la consulta

Comment: Esta pregunta está replicada, Debiera eliminar la anterior si recibirá la respuesta por acá.

Comment: Ya había comentado en esta pregunta, pero fue eliminada, y creada de nuevo acá. Lo que ya te dijeron: recurso o resource es el resultado de la consulta, debes ingresar al resource por medio de un foreach, o bien directamente al array que te retorna en $mon.

Comment: La volvi a preguntar, mas ordenada... Ya consegui el fallo

Comment: Andrea, para futuras preguntas ten en cuenta que las preguntas se pueden [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/145474/edit), en caso de que haga falta mejorar algo. Cuando tú borras una pregunta y creas una nueva lo que haces por lo general es dar un paso atrás en la resolución del problema, ya que probablemente en la pregunta que eliminas hay ya comentarios o respuestas de otros usuarios que pueden servir de ayuda para resolver el problema. Aparte de que borrar la pregunta sería en cierto sentido ignorar el esfuerzo que otros hacen por ayudarte.

Comment: A. Cedano, lo tomare en cuenta!